# UIAlertController action call back performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I found one weird behavior of UIAlertController in Objective-C. I have added two actions in it but I found when user selects any action - handler call back get call after approx 1 sec. I am wondering why this delay is happening to get call back. Is it possible to avoid this by any way?

```
 - (IBAction)openAlert:(id)sender {
        UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                      alertControllerWithTitle:@"Info"
                                      message:@"You are using UIAlertController"
                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction* okBtn = [UIAlertAction
                             actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                             handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                             {
                                 // Delay ~ 1 sec to get control here
                                 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                             }];
        UIAlertAction* cancelBtn = [UIAlertAction
                                 actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                 style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                 handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                 {

                                 }];

        [alert addAction:okBtn];
        [alert addAction:cancelBtn];

        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Its on main thread. To make sure I tried below code snippet.

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

           // Alert view code
            });
```

Comment: 1) Do not attempt to dismiss the alert from any of the alert actions. 2) Is the `openAlert:` method being called on the main queue?

Comment: 1) It doesn't making any difference even though I remove dismiss line of code. 2) Yes Its on main thread.

Comment: This is not relevant, but this line is wrong: `[alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` The user tapping the button will dismiss the alert. You do not need to dismiss it, and it is pointless to try to do so.

Comment: I don't see any code that measures or logs any times. How do you know there's a "delay"?

Comment: I am not able to calculate delay through code . But I can observ it visually by changing color of view. Do u know any way to calculate delay though code? It will help to be more specific.

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", [NSDate date]);` before and after

Comment: @danh... how I can track time of user selection? When user clicks on ok button ? There is delay when user clicks on ok button and call back to handler from IOS framework

Comment: Oh, I see.  Yeah, I don't know.  Can you demo this problem as the first action on the first view controller in the project?  Try to eliminate as a variable anything done in the app the precedes this.

Comment: I tried this in sample app. It has only one viewcontroller and above code . You can copy above code and call on any button action. You will see the difference

Comment: I am thinking in iOS framework they must be dismissing  alert by animation and on completion of animation, they must be passing control to application handler. This is just a guess